# Reducing PDF size to optimize its performance on Kindle?

Tags: pdf, kindle

Is there any tool on Ubuntu that I can use to reduce the physical size of the PDf in terms of it's dimensions so that the file can handle better on a Kindle?

GUI Method please.

Note: PDF has images and text.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pdfsam`; although there is currently a bug with it on 13.04: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pdfsam/+bug/1167469